# Merge two data frames in R by the closest default options, not by excess

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

i have two dataframes:

[df_bestquotes](https://mega.nz/file/C6pRGaCa#2qeKonFU2b7EGRalL1TmEwpt8vkphYRi4WVyzgB-484)

[df_transactions](https://mega.nz/file/azhXhQYQ#ed3x_8QesfpnWHrjo502iT9hurZjrPXxVQpE-CDFHSU)

df_transactions:

```
day time        vol price   buy ask     bid
1   43688,08    100 195,8   1   195,8   195,74
1   56357,34    20  192,87  1   192,87  192,86
1   57576,14    14  192,48  -1  192,48  192,46
2   50468,29    3   193,83  1   193,86  193,77
2   56107,54    11  194,17  -1  194,2   194,16
7   42549,66    100 188,81  -1  188,85  188,78
7   42724,38    200 188,62  -1  188,66  188,61
7   48924,66    5   189,59  -1  189,62  189,59
8   48950,14    52  187,66  -1  187,7   187,66
9   36242,86    89  186,61  1   186,62  186,56
9   53910,46    1   189,81  -1  189,87  189,81
10  47041,94    15  187,87  -1  187,88  187,86
13  34380,73    87  187,29  -1  187,42  187,27
13  36037,18    100 188,94  1   188,95  188,94
14  46644,64    100 189,29  -1  189,34  189,29
14  57571,12    52  190,03  1   190,03  190
15  36418,71    45  192,07  1   192,07  192,04
15  37223,77    100 191,09  -1  191,07  191,06
17  37245,59    100 186,45  -1  186,47  186,45
23  34200,39    50  189,29  -1  189,29  189,27
24  40294,73    60  193,52  -1  193,54  193,5
29  52813,68    5   202,99  -1  203,01  202,99
29  55279,13    93  203,97  -1  203,98  203,9
30  51356,91    68  204,41  -1  204,45  204,4
30  53530,24    40  204,14  -1  204,18  204,14
```

df_bestquotes:

```
day time       best_ask best_bid
1   51384,613   31,78   31,75
1   56593,74    31,6    31,55
3   40568,217   31,36   31,32
7   39169,237   31,34   31,28
8   44715,713   31,2    31,17
8   53730,707   31,24   31,19
8   55851,75    31,17   31,14
10  49376,267   31,06   30,99
16  48610,483   30,75   30,66
16  57360,917   30,66   30,64
17  53130,717   30,39   30,32
20  46353,133   30,72   30,63
23  46429,67    29,7    29,64
24  37627,727   29,81   29,63
24  46354,647   29,92   29,77
24  53863,69    30,04   29,93
24  53889,923   30,03   29,95
24  59047,223   29,99   29,2
28  39086,407   30,87   30,83
28  41828,703   30,87   30,8
28  50489,367   30,99   30,87
29  54264,467   30,97   30,85
30  34365,95    31,21   30,99
30  39844,357   31,06   31
30  57550,523   31,18   31,15
```

For each record of the df_transactions, from the day and time, I need to find the best_ask and the best_bid that was just before that moment, and incorporate this information to df_transactions.

df_joined: df_transactions + df_bestquotes

```
day time        vol price   buy ask     bid     best_ask   best_bid
1   43688,08    100 195,8   1   195,8   195,74
1   56357,34    20  192,87  1   192,87  192,86
1   57576,14    14  192,48  -1  192,48  192,46
2   50468,29    3   193,83  1   193,86  193,77
2   56107,54    11  194,17  -1  194,2   194,16
7   42549,66    100 188,81  -1  188,85  188,78
7   42724,38    200 188,62  -1  188,66  188,61
7   48924,66    5   189,59  -1  189,62  189,59
8   48950,14    52  187,66  -1  187,7   187,66
9   36242,86    89  186,61  1   186,62  186,56
9   53910,46    1   189,81  -1  189,87  189,81
10  47041,94    15  187,87  -1  187,88  187,86
13  34380,73    87  187,29  -1  187,42  187,27
13  36037,18    100 188,94  1   188,95  188,94
14  46644,64    100 189,29  -1  189,34  189,29
14  57571,12    52  190,03  1   190,03  190
15  36418,71    45  192,07  1   192,07  192,04
15  37223,77    100 191,09  -1  191,07  191,06
17  37245,59    100 186,45  -1  186,47  186,45
23  34200,39    50  189,29  -1  189,29  189,27
24  40294,73    60  193,52  -1  193,54  193,5
29  52813,68    5   202,99  -1  203,01  202,99
29  55279,13    93  203,97  -1  203,98  203,9
30  51356,91    68  204,41  -1  204,45  204,4
30  53530,24    40  204,14  -1  204,18  204,14
```

I have tried with the next code, but it doesn't work:

```
library(data.table)
df_joined = df_bestquotes[df_transactions, on="time", roll = "nearest"]
```

Here are the real files with a lot more records, the ones I put before are an example of only 25 records.

[df_transactions_original](https://mega.nz/file/OypTkITY#C6AQpxkg70onxIQ7YoxZc3cvqDXbmPra-yuTJ_2wdug)
[df_bestquotes_original](https://mega.nz/file/XjoxFKTC#017uRgSHbfOg4up7BMFDY9EqQJz1GTvoMHO2dxYhEak)

And my code in R:
[matching.R](https://mega.nz/file/76gxxSQD#yJmYnv-qd9AaML2bXN4Djzp5dFX56v_rZ1Ap82PxNLQ)

Any suggestions on how to get it? Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the new data frame should look like?

Comment: Hi @Michelle, i've updated the original post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The attempt you made uses **data.table** but you don't refer to data.table. Have you done `library(data.table)` before ?

I think it should rather be :

```
df_joined = df_bestquotes[df_transactions, on=.(day, time), roll = TRUE]
```

But I cannot test without the objects. Does it work ? roll="nearest" doesn't give you the previous best quotes but the nearest.

**EDIT :** Thanks for the objects, I checked, that works for me :

```
library(data.table)
dfb <- fread("df_bestquotes.csv", dec=",")
dft <- fread("df_transactions.csv", dec = ",")
dfb[, c("day2", "time2") := .(day,time)] # duplicated to keep track of the best quotes days
joinedDf <- dfb [dft, on=.(day, time), roll = +Inf]
```

It puts `NA` when there is no best quotes for the day. If you want to roll across days, I suggest you create a unique measure of time. I don't know exactly what `time` is. Considering the units of `time` is seconds :

```
dfb[, uniqueTime := day + time/(60*60*24)]
dft[, uniqueTime := day + time/(60*60*24)]
joinedDf <- dfb [dft, on=.(uniqueTime), roll = +Inf]
```

This works even if `time` is not seconds, only the ranking is important in this case.

Comment: Hi @SamuelAllain, i've updated the original post and i replied you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @MiquelMartorellSánchez, thanks for the objects. I edited my answer. When it comes to the error you had, it is due to the "" you added around "day" and "time". You can choose between c("day", "time") and .(day, time)

Comment: Hi @SamuelAllain, thanks for your help. How could I create a single measure of time then? Any suggestion? Thank you again!

Comment: You can choose my answer as the correct one if you're satisfied :)

Comment: One last question @samuelallain: in the joinedDf I am getting many more rows than in the dft. Aren't I supposed to get the same as in dft? Why I have more in the joined if there are only x transactions in the dft? Can you test your code with these two "real" files I send you here please? [link](https://mega.nz/file/XjoxFKTC#017uRgSHbfOg4up7BMFDY9EqQJz1GTvoMHO2dxYhEak) [link](https://mega.nz/file/OypTkITY#C6AQpxkg70onxIQ7YoxZc3cvqDXbmPra-yuTJ_2wdug) Thank you!!!!

Comment: ``df_joined= df_bestquotes[df_transactions, on=c("day", "time"), roll=TRUE, mult="first"]``

Comment: With no single measure of time and the same rows in df_joined and df_transactions now ;) thanks you!!!

Comment: Hi @MiquelMartorellSánchez is your problem settled ? if yes could you accept my answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning @samuelallain, yes, I have used library(data.table) before.
I've edited it in the main commentary.
I have tried its solution and RStudio returns the following error:

```
library(data.table)   
df_joined = df_bestquotes[df_transactions, on=.("day", "time"), roll = TRUE]
```

Error in `[.data.frame`(df_bestquotes, df_transactions, on = .(day, time), :
  unused arguments (on = .("day", "time"), roll = TRUE)

Thank you.